# PayFast - Subscription cancellation on sandbox site

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

How cancel subscription is issued remotely to the PayFast sandbox site?

The assumtion is with either an Ajax PUT or Form PUT.

```html
<form action="https://api.payfast.co.za/subscription/d776203c-341e-c12d-16cb-aa8872d5edee/cancel?testing=true" method="PUT">
 <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="10007713"><input type="hidden" name="merchant_key" value="hagd8cby0yk5o"><input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="https://fraternate.herokuapp.com/payment_finished"><input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="https://fraternate.herokuapp.com/payment_cancelled"><input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://fraternate.herokuapp.com/payment_notify"><input type="hidden" name="name_first" value="Bob"><input type="hidden" name="name_last" value="Smith"><input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="s@gmail.com"><input type="hidden" name="m_payment_id" value="FAKE5551234"><input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1080.00"><input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Single User - Subscription"><input type="hidden" name="item_description" value=""><input type="hidden" name="email_confirmation" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="confirmation_address" value="s@gmail.com"><input type="hidden" name="subscription_type" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="frequency" value="6"><input type="hidden" name="cycles" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="custom_str1" value="s@gmail.com"><input type="hidden" name="custom_str2" value="595b8b63dfbafe053c10e425">
 <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

or

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "PUT", /* or type:"GET" or type:"PUT" */
  crossDomain: true,
  url: 'https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/sb/subs/cancel/f0d6c3bf-223a-958f-e4dd-5c37ef87821b?merchant_id=10007713&merchant_key=hagd8cby0yk5o&return_url=https%3A%2F%2Ffraternate.herokuapp.com%2Fpayment_finished&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Ffraternate.herokuapp.com%2Fpayment_cancelled&notify_url=https%3A%2F%2Ffraternate.herokuapp.com%2Fpayment_notify&name_first=Bob&name_last=Smith&email_address=sd%40gmail.com&m_payment_id=FAKE5551234&amount=1080.00&item_name=Single+User+-+Subscription&item_description=&email_confirmation=1&confirmation_address=sd%40gmail.com&subscription_type=1&frequency=6&cycles=0&custom_str1=sd%40gmail.com&custom_str2=595b8b63dfbafe053c10e425',
  success: function(data){
   console.log('data',)
  },
  error:function(err){
   console.log(err)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However neither of these options work .

There are a number of possible URLS :

```
https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/sb/subs/cancel/d776203c-341e-c12d-16cb-aa8872d5edee
https://api.payfast.co.za/[endpoint]/[token]/[action]?testing=true
https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/subscriptions/d776203c-341e-c12d-16cb-aa8872d5edee/cancel
```

But no success with these items. It appears that some kind of header info needs to be passed into the PUT call with merchcant id ,token and subscription. However, without a sample it is difficult to duplicate.

Any assitance with a sandbox API cancel subscription url post would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is disabled and you therefore cannot send the request via JS on the frontend

Comment: So you are suggesting that the client side needs to pass canecellation req to the express server which should then forward the cancel server side... going to test now.

Answer (score 0):

To update on this.Still not working , but additional progress.

In order to more the cross orgin issue the server needs to post put and get .
This is done with npm require.

```
var request = require('request'); // http requests
var moment = require('moment'); // timestamp
```

The details are for the merchant account on the sandbox

```
Merchant ID :10007713
```

following the details of the developerkit API integration instructions. ( Primary assumption https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process = https://api.payfast.co.za/ )

```js
var timestamp = moment().toISOString();

request.get('https://https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process/subscriptions/ping', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});

request.get('https://https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process/subscriptions/f0d6c3bf-223a-958f-e4dd-5c37ef87821b/ping', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});

request.get('https://https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process/subscriptions/f0d6c3bf-223a-958f-e4dd-5c37ef87821b/ping?merchant_id=10007713&version=v1&timestamp=&'+timestamp+'&signature=dc4a98c5b5ee17540be5ea5cf458efa7', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});

request.put('https://https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process/subscriptions/f0d6c3bf-223a-958f-e4dd-5c37ef87821b/cancel?merchant_id=10007713&version=v1&timestamp=&'+timestamp+'&signature=dc4a98c5b5ee17540be5ea5cf458efa7', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});

request.put('https://https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process/subscriptions/f0d6c3bf-223a-958f-e4dd-5c37ef87821b/cancel:80?merchant_id=10007713&version=v1&timestamp=&'+timestamp+'&signature=dc4a98c5b5ee17540be5ea5cf458efa7', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

All of the above were tested , but no success. various iterations of the sandbox and api and testing were tried. all return 443 error on sandbox and 404 or 401 for the put on cancel subscription.

Any help or examples of the request would be great.

Comment: I see a lot of `https://https://` in the `request.put()` methods, could this be correct?

Answer (score 0):

The PayFast API server does not allow Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

This means that the pre-flight check performed by JQuery when the ajax call is made will fail, as the server response does not contain an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.

The following **will not work** either in your ajax call to the PayFast API:

```
dataType: "json",
jsonp: false,
cache: true,
crossDomain: true,
```

You would need to perform an **ajax call to a server side script**, which then calls the PayFast API. You can then check the result of the API call in the ajax success to provide the user with appropriate feedback.

A response of 404 means your endpoint is not found (incorrect url), the **correct API cancel endpoint** for sandbox is:

`https://api.payfast.co.za/subscriptions/[your sub token]/cancel?testing=true`

Check the [PayFast docs](https://developers.payfast.co.za/documentation/#subscription-payments-api-endpoints) to see how the endpoints should be built, and what the API responses mean (ie. 401 - Merchant authorisation failed)